# Dictionary ContainsValue() causes program to stop responding

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I am using a dictionary to store mesh points, and I don't want to display a [Handle](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handles.FreeMoveHandle.html) for each mesh point because 3 points share the same `Vector3` position, so I am storing the points in a dictionary and then checking the dictionary to see if the value exists, if not add a handle and add the point to the dictionary, otherwise just add the point to the dictionary and not create an extra handle.

When I run this, the editor stops responding and I have to do a force quit, and the thing that is causing the issue is my `if` statement. If I comment out the if it works fine. It also works if I just add all the Handles and use no if, but it runs slowly because of all the handles.

The mesh has about 23k vertices. What can I do to optimize this?

```
public void OnSceneGUI(){
    Creator t = (Creator)target;
    Mesh mesh = t.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
    if (mesh != null) {
        Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;

        Vector3 lp = t.transform.position;
        Handles.color = Color.red;
        Dictionary<int, Vector3> dict = new Dictionary<int, Vector3> ();
        int i = 0;
        foreach (Vector3 v in vertices) {
            Vector3 p = lp - v;
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (p.x, -p.z, p.y);

            if(dict.ContainsValue(pos)){
                Handles.FreeMoveHandle(pos, Quaternion.identity, 0.001f, Vector3.zero, Handles.DotCap);
            }

            dict.Add (i, pos);
            i++;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misusing that `Dictionary` here.

- `ContainsValue` has to enumerate the whole dictionary just to know whether the given value is inside. That's because dictionaries are indexed by *key*, not by *value*. It's an O(n) operation.
- And you only `Add` items to the dictionary, without using the key, then you just drop the dictionary and don't use it for anything else. You're not using the *mapping* feature, which the dictionary is optimized for.

Try with a `HashSet` instead:

```
var handles = new HashSet<Vector3>();

foreach (Vector3 v in vertices) {
    Vector3 p = lp - v;
    Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (p.x, -p.z, p.y);

    if (!handles.Add(pos)) {
        Handles.FreeMoveHandle(pos, Quaternion.identity, 0.001f, Vector3.zero, Handles.DotCap);
    }
}
```

`HashSet`'s `Add` method returns a `bool` that tells you if the value was added (`true`), or if it already existed in the set (`false`).

Comment: It now no longer hangs, but it doesn't place all the verticies

Comment: I guess this is due to a floating point precision issue (you shouldn't compare floating point values for strict equality anyway). Can you check that? If it's due to this reason you could try to `Add` vectors with slightly rounded coordinates to the `handles` collection, which *may* give the expected result, but could also result in some points missing. The real solution in this case would be to use something like an octree instead of a simple `HashSet`.